# Boostrap 3 : ordering elements for different size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, positioning, element

I have 3 divs of 3, 3, 6 width in bootstrap. I want them to be horizontally aligned all the time except for the xs. I want the first 2 div's is one line and the last divs to come below them in small devices. How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div> 
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div> 
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: `col-md-3 col-sm-3` is redundant; just use `col-sm-3`

Comment: Don't forget to make the answer as correct if this is what you are looking for.